# Add | to li tags in menu

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add `|` as the separator to each list element in menu in CSS?

I tried `content: "|"`, but it didn't work.

Menu looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and result is:

`link  link  link  link`

and I want:

`link | link | link | link`

I know how to do it in JavaScript, but CSS would be nicer :) Menu is generated automatically and I don't want to mess around with it.

Comment: Why not use borders instead?

Comment: I agree borders would be the way to go normally. If you still want your pipe, you may use `:before`/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do that with borders:

```css
ul li a { border-left:1px solid #000; display:block; }
```

If you don't want a line on the first, add this:

```css
ul li a:first-child { border:none; }
```

Comment: Minor fix: `border-left:none`

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes you could get that specific if you want, but it's unnecessary

Answer (score 12):

You need to use a pseudo-element for `content`, like `::before` or `::after`:

```css
li + li::before {
    content: "| ";
}
```

[Here’s a  demo.](http://codepen.io/rynah/pen/fdIFm)

As others mentioned though, if you’re looking for a line, use `border-(left|right)` with `padding` or `margin` as necessary.

Comment: (P.S. In case somebody’s looking for IE7/8 compatibility: only use one colon.)

Comment: According to many sources on the internet ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) being one of them) `:before` is only supported by IE8+, not IE7

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful if you posted a fiddle of what you tried so far, but this should work:

```
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content:"|";
}
```

[Working sample on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSV8K/).

Comment: Let me guess: IE8 is out of the game

Comment: @JanDvorak as it damn well should be  :)   I'm just answering the question, it's not my position to decide on the consequences for the resulting site. TS wants to add a pipe character with `content`, this is how you do it.

Comment: You should state the restrictions of your answer with the answer, I believe

Comment: Well most other answers given here also don't work on Firefox 3.5, Chrome 2, IE7 and other extremely outdated browsers, and I don't see them mentioning it. IE8 is 2 major versions old, IE11 is nearly here, I don't really see the point in adding that it doesn't support all newer CSS features.

Comment: While IE7 is pretty much dead, IE8, IMO, isn't. That's why I find it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Use border :

```
li{border-left : 1px solid black;}
li:first-child{border : none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJJCp/).

```
li
{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
li:after
{
    content:"|";
    margin:0px 3px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Didn't notice till after I posted that mine had an extra pipe at the end and someone else also wrote the correct way before me so without getting rid of what I wrote, [here is it updated](http://jsfiddle.net/sJJCp/1/).

```
li
{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
li+li:before
{
    content:"|";
    margin:0px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/SzvQq/

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li:first-child a {
    border-left: none;
}
```